# btrfs: how to calculate btrfs compression space savings?

Tags: linux, btrfs

I've enabled compression (mounted with `compress=lzo`) for my btrfs partition and used it for a while.

I'm curious about how much *benefit* the compression brought me and am interested in the *saved space* value `(sum of all file sizes) - (actual used space)`.

Is there any straightforward way to get this value, or would I have to write a script that sums up e.g. `df` output and compres it to `btrfs filesystem df`output?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt install btrfs-compsize
compsize /mnt/btrfs-partition
```

In Fedora:

```
dnf install compsize
compsize /mnt/btrfs-partition
```

output is like this:

```
Processed 123574 files, 1399139 regular extents (1399139 refs), 69614 inline.
Type       Perc     Disk Usage   Uncompressed Referenced  
TOTAL       73%      211G         289G         289G       
none       100%      174G         174G         174G       
lzo         32%       37G         115G         115G
```

It requires root (`sudo`) to work at all (otherwise `SEARCH_V2: Operation not permitted`).

It can be used on any directory (totalling the subtree), not just the whole filesystem from the mountpoint.

On a system with zstd, but some old files still compressed with lzo, there will be rows for each of them.  (The `Perc` column is the disk_size / uncompressed_size for that row, not how much of the total is compressed that way.  Smaller is better.)

Comment: it is very slow though

Answer (score 5):

Per the [btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression#How_can_I_determine_compressed_size_of_a_file.3F), there's no built-in support for this, but the [compsize](https://github.com/kilobyte/compsize) tool can measure compression on btrfs.

The `df` output will be similar to `btrfs fi df` in that it will report how much disk space is used, not the uncompressed size. The wiki says you can "kind of guess" by comparing `df` output before and after compressing a file. Another option is using some program that will total up the actual data such as `rsync --stats` on a dry run, which will report how much data is read.